# Ant task to build Mac OS X Package

Tags: macos, ant, installation

I'm looking for Ant task which will assemble Mac OS X PKG-file from my application files. Googled. No result. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you get inspiration from this [old mailing post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030619213002144) and use Ant tasks `copy`, `chmod`, `chown`, `tar`, `gzip` instead of commands from shell... It still remains to call the `/usr/bin/package` command with `exec`. Maybe this little Perl script [packagelint](http://gnufoo.org/macosx/macosx.html) may help too.

Comment: i realy ment PKG file. Not DMG file.

Comment: If i understand right there is no special ant task? I've found task for Jar Bundler, thought maybe there is one for PackageMaker. To bad i can't involve Perl as another programming language in project just to build package. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: If I had a MacOS X probably I would be interested in such a Ant task until the point to write it myself... but I run Linux and both a RPM and a dpkg tasks are available.

Comment: Well if I owned a Mac =) I would probably write such Ant task. But i have Mac on work only and it's not my personal machine, it's more like testing and building machine.

Answer (score 1):

So, i have found no special ant task. But i learned how to create Mac OS X package with PackageMaker from inside ant. First you have to create PackageMaker project manually. Create a package in PackageMaker then save it as, say, 'testpkg'. Now you need to add following code in your ant script.

```
<exec executable="/Developer/Applications/Utilities/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker">
                <arg value="--doc"/>
                <arg value="./Installer/testpkg.pmdoc/"/>
                <arg value="--out"/>
                <arg value="${build.dir}/../test.pkg"/>
</exec>
```

Of cource you need to change some arguments to your paths.

This method is simple as if you create package manualy and then reassemble it automatically. But there is another side of medal: every time you have changes in files( e.g. new file must be included in package) you have to change your package project manualy.

There are another ways to create pkg( **packager** tool and variety of command line switches of **PackageMaker** itself). I choose easy way.